# How should I teach a high school student about inverse functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, education, inverse-function

Today I tried to teach a high school student about inverse functions.  I gave him this problem and defined the parts that he didn't understand:

> Let
>
> $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^2 + 1$
>
> $g: [0, \infty) \to [1, \infty)$, $x \mapsto x^2 + 1$
>
> $h: [0, \infty) \to (-\infty, \infty)$, $x \mapsto x^2 + 1$
>
> $p: \{..., -5/2, -3/2, -1/2, 0, 1, 2, ... \} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^2 + 1$
>
> $q: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto 3x + 2$
>
> (a) Which of these functions are one-to-one?
>
> (b) Which of these functions are onto?
>
> (c) Which of these functions have inverses?
>
> (d) What are the inverses?  Over what domains are the inverses defined?
>
> (e) For the functions that have inverses, evaluate those inverses at $x = -1$.

However, I think he found the problem too difficult.  What would be better problems to give him?  More generally, what could I have done to help him better understand inverse functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Three of the four functions that have inverses can’t be evaluated at $-1$, because $-1$ isn’t in the domain of the inverse. The symbol $x$ is *not* tied to the domain of the original function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When introducing the ideas of one-to-one and onto to my students, I like to begin with some
simple pictures so they can "see" what's going on. For example,

[image: onto and not]

Draw a nice little picture of an onto function (the one I've drawn isn't one-to-one). Then add some more dots in the codomain and voila! It's not onto anymore. Draw a few pictures to illustrate one-to-one as well. To picture inverse functions draw a one-to-one, onto function and then "flip" all of the arrows and you've got the inverse.

Draw a bunch of pictures adding and deleting points to make functions one-to-one and/or onto or not.

Next, I'd play around with the example: $f(x)=x^2$.

1) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is neither one-to-one or onto.

Why? Showing something fails to be onto is simple, merely find something in the codomain
   that doesn't get "hit". So for example $-1$ is not in the range. When we try to solve 
   the equation $f(x)=x^2=-1$, the only solutions we get are $x = \pm \sqrt{-1}$ 
   (which fail to be in our domain). So nothing maps to $-1$. Thus it's not in the range so
   not onto.

2) Then ask, "How could we 'fix' the function so it is onto?"

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} = [0,\infty)$. Now the equation $f(x)=x^2=y$
can always be solved: $x = \pm \sqrt{y}$ (which are real since $y \geq 0$.

Next, note that there are two solutions for each (non-zero) $y$. So the function isn't one-to-one.

3) How can we "fix" $f$ again so that it's one-to-one?

$f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$

Now $f(x)=f(y)$ so $x^2=y^2$ implies that $x=y$.

4) So finally, $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is bijective (one-to-one and onto). How can we find an inverse? Go back to what N.S. suggests: it's all about solving for "x" given the equation $y=x^2$. We solve $x=\pm \sqrt{y}$ remembering that we're only allowed non-negative solutions $x=\sqrt{y}$. So $f^{-1}:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is defined by $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Make sure to check $f(f^{-1}(x))=(\sqrt{x})^2=x$ (the inverse works on the right because $f$ is onto) and $f^{-1}(f(x))=\sqrt{x^2}=x$ (the inverse works on the left because $f$ is one-to-one).

I hope this gives you a few ideas to help get started. :)

Comment: (+1) Regarding pictures and flipping, another good one is to take a one-to-one function and draw the inverse by reflecting the graph across the line $y=x$. Doing this with non one-to-one functions then also proves instructive, and even provides an opportunity to reinforce the definition (and intuitive notions) of a function.

Comment: Good idea. I neglected the geometric side of things because I typically think of teaching this stuff at the beginning of an abstract algebra course. When working with functions defined on subsets of the reals, certainly seeing properties like one-to-one (passing the horizontal line test) can be quite helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful and detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

The approach I find most intuitive is via equations.

Ask him to solve the equation $x^2+1=y$ for $x$, and then ask him if the answer he gets is a function...

Start building for there:

For which $y$ does this equation have solution(s)? When is the solution a function (i.e., unique)? Write the solution as a function in $y$... Which is the largest domain? What is the range?

What is the connection between this function, domain , range and the original function?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it can easily encourage students to think of finding the inverse as a mechanical operation, just another mysterious manipulation of symbols followed by an even more mysterious interchange of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah that was the way I learned it in middle school...